# Why does Godzilla change size so dramatically in the 2014 film?

Tags: godzilla-2014, monsterverse

In the movie *Godzilla (2014)*, the eponymous monster's size seems to fluctuate dramatically in relation to the humans around him. At times he seems about 300 feet tall but at other times much larger or smaller.

Is it simply bad CGI or am I missing something in the plotline?

Comment: Are you asking if Godzilla is smaller in the 2014 film as opposed to earlier releases?

Comment: No, he is making a comment about the uneven CGI effects in the recent Godzilla, where even though Godzilla is very tall, often scenes would have the monster feeling a bit out of sync with the Human-sized characters. It is a slight disconnect, all things considered bit you can see it if you watch carefully.

Comment: I've tried to make this a little clearer. It's quite a big edit though. Roll it back if you think I've gone too far.

Comment: Godzilla changes size in all the original films too.  Treat it as an homage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As with most monster films, the size of the monster shifts to fit in with the scene, with little or no regard for any canonically confirmed height/weight/size.

In the [2014 reboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_(2014_film)) of Godzilla, the monster fits neatly into a train tunnel (100+ feet), strolls past a 30-storey building (350+ feet high), swims alongside an aircraft carrier (1000+ feet) before attacking the Golden Gate bridge (600+ feet including draught).

Ultimately you have to accept that this is a conscious decision on the part of the filmmakers to tell a story and that any inconsistencies are accountable only to [Bellisario's Maxim](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim);

> **Don't examine this too closely**

[image]

Comment: I'm curious if any Kaiju movie ever actually *tried* to justify the rapid change in size of the Kaiju for obvious cinematic fight purposes.  Possibly having to do with rapid shedding/consumption of gamma radiation.

Comment: I don't know enough about the original Godzilla movies to pass comment. That might make a good question if you can come up with a couple of examples

Comment: Unfortunately I also lack enough experience to come up with solid examples.

Answer (score 0):

He doesn't. I can point this out. He does swim along side a carrier but is not shown to be bigger than it. He is around 900 ft swimming anyway from head to tail. He never in the film went through a train tunnel. The other monster was out side surrounding the tunnel because of a mountain face. He smashes through the golden gate bridge but is never shown to be bigger than it and he stands at 355 ft. You don't just randomly select a size for every scene you have to keep continuity. The CGI artists made him 355 ft tall, taill, 550 ft long and so forth. Also buildings are varied sizes the one that collapses on him is almost double his size at 600 and something ft where as other buildings are smaller than him. Also you have to look at perspective. Far away and small. It is most certainly not bad cg . it is some of the best I've ever seen. Trust me I've done the research, watched all the behind the scenes and have seen the film a dozen times. Twice in cinema.

Comment: The Golden Gate scene is based on the fact people most people don't realize the channel beneath it is so deep.